# Interchange of Suprema

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets and $f:A \times B \to \mathbb{R}$. Then is it true that suprema interchange ? i.e.
$$\sup_{s \in A}\sup_{t \in B} f(s,t)\overset{?}{=}\sup_{t \in B}\sup_{s \in A} f(s,t)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the chain of inequalities:
$$f(s,t)\leq\sup_{(s,t)}f(s,t)\Rightarrow\sup_s f(s,t)\leq\sup_{(s,t)}f(s,t)\Rightarrow\sup_t\sup_s f(s,t)\leq\sup_{(s,t)}f(s,t)$$
and similar chain of inequalities:
$$f(s,t)\leq\sup_s f(s,t)\leq\sup_t\sup_s f(s,t)\Rightarrow\sup_{(s,t)}f(s,t)\leq\sup_t\sup_s f(s,t)$$
So both together:
$$\sup_t\sup_s f(s,t)=\sup_{(s,t)} f(s,t)$$

The analogous result then holds for interchanged indices:
$$\sup_s\sup_t f(s,t)=\sup_{(s,t)} f(s,t)$$

Concluding:
$$\sup_t\sup_s f(s,t)=\sup_{(s,t)} f(s,t)=\sup_s\sup_t f(s,t)$$